# Symfony3 index page

Tags: symfony

I have written a series of working controllers within the directory /src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin, such as DoctorAdminController, PatientAdminController, etc. The top of these controllers look like so:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 */
class DoctorAdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/doctor", name="admin_doctor_list")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I can navigate to each page exactly as expected:
http://example.com/admin/doctor

I would like to have a page sitting at http://example.com/admin, but for the life of me can't get get a working route. I have this as the controller for the index page:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 */
class DefaultAdminController extends Controller
{
    /*
     * @Route("/", name="default_admin")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->render('admin/admin_base.html.twig');
    }

}
```

I have my routing.yml file set to annotations:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

When I try to access http://example.com/admin, I get a "No route found for GET /admin" error. Consistent with this, when I use `./bin/console debug:router` there is no route listed for /admin, but I do see routes for all others (/admin/doctor, etc.)

What am I missing?

Comment: OK, it just started working. I have no idea why. Any insight appreciated. I had previously cleared the cache (didn't help) and did not try clearing again before things started working. Weird.

Comment: I found the error. Very subtle!! In my annotations block above the function, I started the line with '/*' instead of '/**'. That made all the difference. Fixed now.

Comment: I ran into the exact [same problem previously](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/70#issuecomment-199098709); so `/*` is a comment. That's why it doesn't get recognized.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have your routing annotation before the class. You shouldn't do that, but instead put it in front of your actions only, like so:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultAdminController extends Controller
{
    /*
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->render('admin/admin_base.html.twig');
    }

}
```

I also show this with the "name" using "admin" as well, so you can also specify "admin" in Twig and redirects using the same name; this is so it will make sense to you. Same thing for your `DoctorAdminController`, remove the routing annotation before the class.

That should fix the problems.

Comment: It actually works with the routing annotation before the class, and functions to preface other routes. I agree it's easier to follow the way you did it, I was just following a tutorial that showed me that one and I left it. Thanks though.